# .net site causes file download instead of showing specific pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, exe

On a customers site certain pages (two that I know of) trigger the download of a TeamViewer exe file that is on the server instead of showing the linked aspx page.

This was brought to our attention today and I'm not sure when it started.

I've gone over the routing and generic page handler in our system and I don't find anything out of the ordinary.

Is there any known reason this could happen that relates to server configuration or similar?

I've tried it in multiple different browsers and the download is triggered in each of them (Chrome, Chromium and Opera).

The file in question is not linked in the pages. The contents of the pages are being fetched from a database using the same system as the non-problematic pages.

Comment: What is the controller attempting to return, keep in mind that `IActionResult` can return an assortment of return types.  Can we see the Controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

Turns out someone added a redirect to this exe file in web.config which matched "tv" (for TeamViewer) in the url, and matched for example "tjanster-programu**tv**eckling" which was one of the problem pages.

I guess whoever added that redirect expected it to only apply to the whole url, not just a partial match.

I've commented out this redirect and now the pages load properly.

Comment: It probably goes without saying but either add a comment in the config file that explains why it was commented out, or hunt down the person who originally added this (if even possible, system configuration documentation?) or fix the configuration so that the "tv" redirect still works where it is supposed to, otherwise we, and you, are just a question away from "Why did my TeamViewer download stop working? oh, I'll just uncomment these lines". Tennis is a good sport but best not played in configuration files (old saying).

Comment: If something stops working I'll be made aware eventually, but I don't think this was actually used (anymore) since the files are directly linked on a specific download page. I'm the only one responsible for these config files at the moment.